# Differences between some parameters in SMPP

Tags: message, wireshark, smpp

I would like to understand the differences between the next parameters:

```
smpp.data_coding
smpp.dcs
smpp.dcs.charset
```

It seems to be that the vale of smpp.data_coding and smpp.dcs always match. However, I'm not sure if the value of smpp.dcs could be different of the value of smpp.data_coding.
I was looking for some information, but it isn't still clear for me, so I appreciate your help.

Thank you.

Kind regards,

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure if its gonna help, maybe you have read it already but there is not much of the difference contextually between data_coding and dcs. However, data_coding field is restricted to sharing 1 byte of value and representing what coding is being used. While, with dcs in addition to the 1 byte of data  that is associated about the coding scheme, we also get additional attribute fields like - charset.

This may not be significant in general sense, but check this out - https://helpx.adobe.com/in/campaign/kb/smpp-protocol-wireshark.html

> The data_coding field tells you which encoding is used. The only problem is that the value 0 means default SMS-C encoding in the specification, but in general it means GSM7. Check with the SMS-C partner what encoding is associated to data_coding = 0 (Adobe Campaign only supports GSM7 for data_coding = 0).

Hence, while value of data_coding and dcs might look same, dcs.charset helps identify the character set being used and hence the message size too.
Maybe you have figured it out already..